# Ventana modal con Laravel 8 livewire dentro de la plantilla AdminLTE

Tags: laravel, adminlte

Alguien ha utilizado ventanas modales con laravel 8 y la plantilla adminlte??? Llevo toda la tarde intentándolo y no hay manera.
Laravel 8 a traves de los componentes facilita mucho el uso de los modales pero con la plantilla adminlte no funciona. (no se porque ) mis conocimientos son basicos.
Se que con bootsrap y js se podria hacer pero no existe ninguna manera de poder utilizar los componentes de livewire? Gracias!

No puedo mostrar ningun error porque no los muestra, ni en consola ni en pantalla.
He descubierto que los componentes modales de livewire no funcionan porque cuando los utilizo fuera de adminlte si se disparan.

Comment: Ayudaría que describas mejor el *por que crees que los componentes no funcionan* cuando escencialmente son solo php

Comment: Pues como he comentado, no hay nigun error en pantalla ni en consola. Pero si utilizo los componentes en otra ruta donde no esta Adminlte si que funcionan, por lo que entiendo que debe de existir algun conflicto entre ambas. Por eso preguntaba, por si alguien ya tiene experiencia y sabe como hacer que funcionen..

Comment: Importastes lo necesario para utilizar livewire?

Comment: me encuentro en la misma situación que tu, es algún conflicto como tu bien dices, pero no consigo averiguar que es exactamente para solucionarlo.
Encontraste la solución?